# Active Directory Sites: Remote site is smaller subnet in main site's subnet definition

Tags: active-directory

Currently, we have one site *Default-First-Site* - Gross default name, I know. We have plans to add a remote site. The the main site is a 172.18.0.0/16 that is split into dozens of smaller subnets. The remote site is connected to us by a [MAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_area_network). Essentially, it is a 20Mbps bidirectional link between the main site and the remote site. The remote site is 172.18.228.0/22, which is obviously in the 172.18.0.0/16 range.

I am setting up DFS, a RODC, and a few other things for that remote site and have now set up a site for in in Active Directory so that the clients will connect to the appropriate DFS member and use the RODC that is on-site. We'll call this site *Remote-Site* for this question. In AD Sites I defined the 172.18.228.0/22 as belonging to *Remote-Site*. I have no subnet definition for *Default-First-Site*.

My question is, do I need to define 172.18.0.0/16 as the subnet for *Default-First-Site*, or will anything not in *Remote-Site* assume it is part of *Default-First-Site*? Also, if I define 172.18.0.0/16 as the subnet for *Default-First-Site*, will that screw up anything in *Remote-Site*, since 172.18.228.0/22 is obviously a subnet of 172.18.0.0/16?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have overlapping subnets in AD and they'll behave as you'd expect. A less-specific "catch all" subnet, like 172.16.0.0/16, will be selected by clients unless a more specific subnet, like 172.16.228.0/22, is defined in the Sites container.

So, define the 172.16.0.0/16 subnet and associated it with your Default-First-Site-Name site (which you can rename to be less ugly), and then create addt'l sites and subnets for the remote locations with more specific subnets inside 172.16.0.0/16 specified.

You can read [a more in-depth article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.06.subnets.aspx) if you want more details, but based on your question I think you already understand what you're looking for and your expected behavior is the product's designed behavior.